# Debugger cell is not being displayed in jupyter lab (Version 4.0.8)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am having trouble opening the debugger cell in Jupyter Lab for my assignment. I have written the code in Jupyter notebook and need to debug it in Jupyter Lab. I am using version 6.28.0 of ipykernel.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtZ1U.png)

I have been trying to find a solution to this problem I'm facing. However, most of the people I found have the same kernel version above 6 and don't seem to have any issues. I have already tried running the command `conda create -n jupyterlab-debugger -c conda-forge jupyterlab=3 "ipykernel>=6" xeus-python`, but it didn't work. I'm new to Jupyter Lab and haven't used it before this, so I would appreciate some guidance on how to solve this issue. Thank you in advance for your help!"

Comment: You need updated tech and then you don't need to include xeus-python. You seem to be reading outdated things because though because if install more recent things than ipykernel will work, see 'Support for the Jupyter Debugger Protocol just landed in ipykernel' [here](https://blog.jupyter.org/enabling-the-jupyterlab-debugger-with-ipykernel-8d7248f522b0)? If you have a choice, I'd suggest just starting with version 4 ...

Comment: <continued> as your title references. You don't want `jupyterlab=3` that you leave in for the command `conda create -n jupyterlab-debugger -c conda-forge jupyterlab=3 "ipykernel>=6" xeus-python` that you say you tried. Be aware that example code there may not be the most current and you are expected to know to adapt it to what you need. If you are using the Anaconda Distribution, I believe the default stuff should have already come set up to use the Debugger. Did you try opening JupyterLab from within the Anaconda Navigator?

Comment: By the way of comparison, if you need a place to test the debugger where it is already set up correctly, go [here](https://gist.github.com/jtpio/f3f7aed7c87bb15e07009bb29a601ed8) and click on the 'launch binder' badge. That session that comes up will let you use it with the ipykernel. Just look for the 'Enable Debugg' icon that is the 'little bug' icon along the top, between the two up and down cloud icons, and click it to turn it orange. The debugger panel on the right side should then open automatically.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I have been accessing the JupyterLab through Anaconda Navigator. I went through the [documentation](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/debugger.html)
 again, and installed `xeus-python`. Now the debugging features are available to use.

Comment: Weird. You shouldn't have needed it for it to work with ipykernel. But maybe when you added that kernel, it also installed correctly something else that wasn't quite right. Glad it is all worked out now though.

Comment: You may want to see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-add-debugger-to-jupyter-lab/24517/11?u=fomightez). Adjusting the json in the `kernel.json` configuration file allowed it to work with ipykernel for that person.